# Show Blank Page On Direct Load (PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess, redirect

I currently use an external service for a price comparison unit I have on one of my sites. The way you load the price comparison block is via javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://www.easycontentunits.com/js_unit.php?ecu_mid=3706&amp;ecu_uid=101734"></script>
```

If you were to paste the above code into a html page, you would see a block of prices, more info buttons etc. However, if you loaded the source page directly, it shows no content and a completely blank page:

```
http://www.easycontentunits.com/js_unit.php?ecu_mid=3706&amp;ecu_uid=101734
```

I am looking to write some code for another site I run and would like it to work like the example above. I.E. when I load an external php page via javascript, it will show it on the webpage. If you followed the link and loaded the external page it would show a blank page.

How would you go about this? Is it some special php code, or a trick with htaccess or similar?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: when I change the url to `www.easycontentunits.com/js_unit.php?ecu_mid=3706&ecu_uid=101734` (ie. change the &amp to &) it works just fine - loading it directly

Comment: My apologies. That was a rookie error on my part! Is there any way to do the above however? As it is still something that I would like to try and implement.

Comment: scibuff's point is correct -- entities make sense in HTML code only. When typing URL in location bar of browser, corresponding character (`&`) should be used instead of its entity (`&amp;`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely what you want is just `referer` request header check:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

Comment: A referrer check does indeed achieve the desired effect, but note that a `Referer` header can be very easily spoofed, so it is by no means a solid "protection". Also, some users may have configured their clients to omit or manipulate referrers, so the script wouldn't work for them even when it is embedded into a page.

Answer (score 0):

They are most likely checking the HTTP_REFERER value in the $_SERVER superglobal, and returning a blank page when the referrer is not the correct site.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Although I have made a mistake above when trying to load the direct link (should of just used the & on its own), I would still like to try and come up with a solution.